# Orange color on camshaft

Tags: nissan, camshaft, micra

Engine HR12DE
Model: Nissan Micra K13 2011

Hello, as I was replacing the timing chain I noticed some orange color on the intake camshaft toward the back of the engine.
Is this worrying ? I appreciate your help!

Picture linked below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing on this, but I'll bet the orange stripe indicates the intake cam, while the yellow stripe on the other indicates the exhaust cam. The stripes are in the same relative place on the cams. Any which way, this paint is not on the camshaft lobes, nor on the journals, so it is absolutely nothing to worry about.